# File transfer between linux mint pc and windows pc through ethernet cable

Tags: networking, linux-mint, ethernet

I'm a newbie in linux mint. I have a linux mint 18 laptop and a windows 8.1 desktop. I want to share files between two computers. I have no router. But I have lan cable. Thus I want to connect two pc through lan cable. How can I connect two pc through lan cable without router when one of them is windows pc and another one is linux mint pc. And can I transfer files between two pc. 
As I am a newbie step by step suggestion is needed. I will be grateful if anyone help me.
Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

You need an ethernet crossover cable (one side with the T568A configuration, and the other with the T568B configuration) or a crossover adaptor to connect two devices of the same type, otherwise the computers won't identify each other.

After they are connected with the correct cable/adaptor, the computers should identify themselves automatically creating a local network between themselves and see the files (or the folder) that have permission to be shared on a network.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a Crossover Adapter: Cat6/Cat5e Ethernet RJ45 Male/Female Adapter to Connect 2 Computers with a Standard Lan Cable.

Reason? 2, actually. 1. Then you can use it with any length and location cable you need. 2. If the crossover cable is not clearly marked and you have a collection of Ethernet cables, the crossover cable can be lost in the milieu. An adapter prevents that.

Amazon for one sells the crossover adapter. Search for the descriptive title above. One such sells presently for around $5.

Regards.